# from mongo to postgresql - error: syntax error at or near "array_to_string"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, node-postgres

I am trying to learn databases and nodejs.

I want to ask how can I translate the following from mongod to postgresql using nodejs.

```
//fill QueryString
collection.find({"myID" : {$in:QueryString} },{}).toArray(function(err, Stuff) { 

.....

if ( .... ) {

collection.update(
      { "myID" : req.body.id },
      {$set : { "myField" : req.body.fileid }}, 
      function(err, resultNew) {
..
}//end of update
}//end of find
```

I tried :

```
//fill QueryString
for (var i=0; i<req.body.my_ids.length; i++) {
    QueryString[i] = req.body.my_ids[i]; 
}

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {

        if (err) return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);


       client.query("SELECT FROM mytable WHERE myID = ANY  array_to_string(QueryString::int[],', ') ", function(err, Stuff) {
           ....

          client.query("UPDATE mytable WHERE myID = 'req.body.id' SET myField ='req.body.fileid' " , function(err,result) {

            });//end of update

            }); // end of select
```

I am not sure my translations.

In the first query when using mongo , the "Stuff" will be an array and I have to do some calculations with it, but in node-postgres?Will it be an array ,or I have to specify something?Right now  I can't find the appropriate syntax to search in QueryString.

In the second query I am not sure at all if it is right,or how can I write it.

Answer (score 0):

So , it seems that this works:

```
client.query( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id = ANY ($1::varchar[])  ",[QueryString], function(err, Stuff) {

client.query("UPDATE mytable  SET myField ='req.body.fileid' WHERE my_id = 'req.body.id'",  function(err, result)  {
```